# How do you fetch child/sub elements (in my case the choice between condiments for a meal) from Firebase RTDB in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My tree table for a menutItem is as follows:

```
menuItem
        J1
           -description:"Tasty milk shake!"
           -img:"assets/images/milkshake.JPG"
           -itemName:"Milk Shake"
           -price:20
           -varieties
                    -var1:"Chocolate"
                    -var2:"Vanilla"
                    -var3:"Strawberry"
```

I am using a stream builder to fetch the information from the each record to populate my menu and once a menu is selected (i.e. onPress) I pass on the relevant information to the item page where they can view more and add to cart. I want to fetch the different varieties of certain meals so the customer can choose what they want via radio buttons.

Currently I am counting the widgets in the StreamBuilder list and fetching the varieties for each menu item by adding J to each number counted to form the correct ID. This allows me to get the right values for an item but I can't store/attach the variety options to the correct widget it belongs to.

My StreamBuilder code is as follows:

```
StreamBuilder(
            
            stream: _dbRef.child('menuItem').onValue,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final tilesList =
                  <InkWell>[]; 

              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final myRewards = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                    (snapshot.data! as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                        as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);

                myRewards.forEach((key, value) {
                  final nextReward = Map<String, dynamic>.from(
                      value); 

                  final price = nextReward['price'];
                  String itemName = nextReward['itemName'];
                  String desc = nextReward['description'];
                  String itemImg = nextReward['img'];

                  final rewardTile = InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        var pls = options;

                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ItemPageState(
                                  itemName: itemName,
                                  desc: desc,
                                  price: price,
                                  itemImg: itemImg,
                                )));
                        // }
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 10, 8, 10),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              ClipRect(
                                  child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                widthFactor: 0.8,
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(itemImg),
                                  height: 100,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(width: 30),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    itemName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Price: R' + price.toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 30),
                              
                            ]),
                      ));

                  tilesList.add(rewardTile);
                  count = tilesList.length;
                 
                });
                getOptions(count);
              }
```

My "get options" code is as follows:

```
Future<void> getOptions(int count) async {
      for (var itemNum = 1; itemNum <= count; itemNum++) {
        String strItemNum = itemNum.toString();
        String itemID = 'J$strItemNum';

        final hope = await _dbRef.child('menuItem/$itemID/varieties').get();
        if (hope.exists) {
          options.add(hope.value.toString());
        }
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this? And am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: `builder` needs you to return it a widget to build when you are done with the values. Currently, you are adding them to a list, but not doing anything with them. Return a widget containing these `InkWell`s so that it has something to display, such as a `Column` or `ListView`

Comment: I am returning a widget for the stream builder I just left the code out because I am not having an issue with displaying information. My question was how I can access and set the varieties part of my items in the database and associate those variety options with the correct meal so that when I choose to view a milkshake I will get options, Vanilla/Chocolate/Strawberry not Lemon&Herb/Medium/Peri Peri.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Dart docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/builder.html), the `builder` property of `StreamBuilder` needs you to return a Widget to display when the value is being processed. Make sure not to change any outside values (also known as "introducing side-effects") in the `builder` function, and only return a widget to be displayed.

Since you are creating `InkWell`s, you should return them in a widget that displays multiple children, such as `Column` or `Builder`:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  final tilesList = <InkWell>[]; 

  // fill tilesList with widgets

  return Column(children: tilesList);
}
```

Also, as it seems to me that `getOptions` is creating another async operation -  you should avoid this as it might cause unwanted bugs. Instead, make one stream that handles all the data in sequence and use *that* in your `stream` argument, or, build more children widgets that will be asynchronously loaded the same way (using more `StreamBuilder`s or similal widgets).

Comment: Thank you for tip on the async method but my StreamBuilder does return widgets and it does work. However, I want to go the next step and display all the correct varieties of the meals when you click on the initial menu card and get redirected to the Item Page where they can then choose between, in the case of a milkshake, chocolate/vanilla/strawberry and other options if I wanted to view a full chicken meal.